# How can I add an extra border of 5 pixels on my controls?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add an extra border (thick) on my controls like here: http://tickspot.com/screenshots/

As we see in this link, the combos list and textbox have a blue tick border.

How can I achieve this without too much effort?

Thank you.

Comment: you mean other than "border: solid #00a 5px;" in the style or css?

Comment: Which tech are you using? Please re-tag your question!! That'd hard instead.. :)

Comment: @Babak: I mean I would like a double border. A solution with outline seems a good solution but I would like the same behavious (border) when control has focus or not.

Comment: @Matías: I use ASP.NET MVC and I would like a css solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS only solution might be to use both `border` and `outline` styles : http://jsfiddle.net/RyJzC/

(But remember `outline` is used to give an indication that an element has focus so make sure you take this behaviour into account if you do style `outline`)

Comment: this solution is fine for me but when the control has the focus, the outline changed to a smaller border. I prefer to keep same outline when control is focused or not. How can I do?

Comment: Use something like input:focus { ..styles..} to set the style for when the input has focus. (Ideally set the focus style to be slightly different to the normal style to indicate to the user which element has focus. This will make your form more usable.)

Answer (score 0):

You may nest your elements and give the outer element the border and the padding.
here you'll get an impression: http://jsfiddle.net/jy92c/1/

Comment: edited my example which now contains a text box with a border.

Answer (score 0):

**Not all form elements properly support css styling**.  You could probably find some styles that work across the board, but it might take some work.

The easier option to get consistency is to **wrap your controls in a `<span class='control'></span>`**  The downside to this method is that you have to add extra markup.  You could give all the elements on your page `class='addBorder'` or something similar and then use JavaScript to find them and wrap them. That'd be a very unobtrusive method.  Comment if you need help on implementing this and I'd be happy to help.